# What is type of object is returned by the Request in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to know that what type of object is returned by the request object in scrapy

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Suppose this is my request

```
myrequest = Request("http://www.example.com",  callback = self.mytest)
```

Now i want to know what will be in the `myrequest` variable.

is there any way to override the Request object because i want to create `MYREQUEST` which returns response object so that i can acess `resposne.body` , `resposne.url`

```
myvar =MYREQUEST("http://www.example.com",  callback = self.mytest)
```

then i can access `myvar.body` and `myvar.url`

I could not find Request Class defination from git hub where is that class defined.
i can oly find request folder there but not Request Class
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/tree/master/scrapy/http

Comment: couldn't you just use `type()` to find the type of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request` is a `class`, so you are not calling a function here, what really happens is that you created a `Request` object and assigned it to `myreqeust`.

As stated in `Scrapy`'s [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions):

> The callback function will be called with the downloaded Response
>   object as its first argument.

Comment: but how can i get the response object out of callback function. i want that if i call request then i get back resposne object. i can get that in callback fucntion but i am not able to get that out from that function. i mean its available in mytest but i am not able get that from outside of mytest callback

Comment: wow , thanks for clarification. i am now understanding something. is there any way i can access resposne from that myrequest which i have created something like `myrequest.response.body`. in otherwords where does things gets stored which are returned by the callable

Comment: @user1858407 When you create a `Request` object, the request doesn't get sent automatically. To get a response object, first you'll need to find out how to really send the request, probably with a `Downloader`. You can find more information about this class in the document.

Comment: i am not able to find the class defination in the scrapy docs so that i know how its coded

Comment: @user1858407 Type `import scrapy; scrapy` in your Python shell, and you'll see the way to `scrapy`'s source code.

Comment: I think i will need to ask separate question for manually processing the request